# How to Export SharedPreferences to csv, xls, or vcard

Tags: java, android, csv, sharedpreferences, export-to-csv

How would I export all of my shared preferences (which are values such as Name, Phone, Email, Address concatenated into one string and separated by a delimiter ",") by giving the user the option to choose between formats like csv, xls, or vcard? I will eventually switch to using a sqlite database which I think is easier to export in this manner, but for now I am learning about sharedPreferences.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all your shared pref values and do whatever you want with them like this

```
Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPref.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
    Log.d("TAG", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Comment: I think I sort of understand what that does, but where would I code for export etc? after the last toString());?